# How to delete thumbnail when I delete the original picture using Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I created an Azure function to create a thumbnail every time an user uploads a picture to my storage container.

My problem is, how can I delete the thumbnail when the user deletes the picture? Can I use a Blob Trigger? Should I use a Time Trigger to check which thumbnail doesn't have an associated picture and delete that thumbnail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blob trigger won't fire for deleted blobs

> your function code is called when a new or updated blob is detected

A couple options I can suggest:

1. If files are deleted via the code that you control, you could send a queue message every time a blob is deleted, and then delete thumbnails when you receive this queue message.
2. [Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview) seems to support Deletes:

   > Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted: Fired when a blob is deleted through a DeleteBlob operation

   So you can make an Event Grid triggered function and filter on this event type, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Azure Event Trigger is the way to do it but right now it is a preview and it is only available in US. Don't want to risk my production app with a preview version. Seems I have to wait to use it.